# emacs yasnippet expand a list

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to have yasnippet expand out a list. Ideally I'd like to have a list of items, for example:

```
'((ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND "The file was not found")
  (ERROR_SERVER_CRASHED "Server has crashed"))
```

I'd like to pass that to the snippet when expanding so that I can output a block of code for each list item. Currently I would do this sort of thing with a bit of custom list code, but I'm just curious if you can do it with a yasnippet.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. What would you like to have as output ?